# VS Console window does not show all results

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS express 2012 to run a code that display content of many files. I found that first files content do not show and when I debug step by step I found that the content show on the console window and disappear when other results show, which means they get pushed out of the window. of course I scroll up and I find the latest files only not all. Is there any option control this feature? and how can I see all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this you should convert your console application to a Windows Forms one and put all the output on a TextBox. Just execute the command on the Form load and redirect all the output to the TextBox.

It's not much work IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of a console application, no different than if you were to echo data to the Windows command prompt. If there is too much data then of course it will scroll off the visible screen.